# ARIMA(0,0,0) model but residuals not white noise

Tags: arima, model-selection, autocorrelation, residuals, white-noise

I have a dataset where I am trying to fit an ARIMA model to a stock return - the data set is stationary. I have used the Auto.Arima function to select appropriate AR and MA terms, and BIC selects ARIMA(0,0,0) - which indicates white noise.

However, when I conduct a Ljung-Box test on the residuals i cannot confirm white noise.
Can a conclusion to this be that even though BIC recommends ARIMA(0,0,0) the LB test suggests that it might not be white noise after all?

Comment: autoarima does not have to be right - nothing is perfect. I would try other models and see if the LB test suggests then there is no serial correlation.

Comment: Some patterns are so weak that modelling them introduces more noise than captures the signal. `auto.arima` can intensionally leave some mildly autocorrelated time series unmodelled (i.e. ARIMA(0,0,0)) as any model that you fit would likely perform worse than ARIMA(0,0,0) due to estimation imprecision.

Comment: How do you do the test? Note that residual from autoregressive models still have the same autocorrelation as in a standard model, the CAR / ARIMA structure does not fit an explicit estimator for the local CAR structure, it just accounts for it in the calculation of the model parameters / p-values. You can try this out while going through a few example models.

Comment: @RichardHardy: how do we handle such series then? Does this mean that if there were more observations, we would either get some other model than ARIMA(0,0,0) or LB test would give uncorrelated errors? If not, what can be said about the DGP?

Comment: We handle them as ARIMA(0,0,0). If you get a larger sample, you might fit some other ARIMA model with sufficient precision so that it beats ARIMA(0,0,0). LB test does not have to indicate uncorrelated errors in either case. It is hard to say anything concrete about the DGP besides that autocorrelations are weak.

Comment: @FlorianHartig, what model do you have in mind? Probably regression with ARMA errors? If the true DGP is ARMA(p,q) and we fit an ARMA(p,q), the residuals will be approximately white noise. They will not have the same autocorrelation as the original time series.

Comment: @RichardHardy, sorry, I misread the question, although it's written there in plain sight I somehow thought it was about why there still can be autocorrelation in general in ARIMA residuals, not specifically about ARIMA(0,0,0) ...OK, I will attempt an explanation.